# Python Pandas - Vlookup - Update Existing Column in First Data Frame From Second Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching for the most pythonic way to achieve the following task:

first data frame:

```
df1 = 

     dataA  dataB   key  info  dataC
0     ABC    123    a1b         aaa
1     DEF    456    b57         bbb
2     GHI    789    a22         ccc
```

second data frame:

```
df2 = 

    dataX   key   info    dataY
0    KLJ    a1b   infoA    hhh
1    RTY    q3z   infoB    uuu
2    PUI    a22   infoC    ppp
```

first data frame after pythonic operations:

```
df1 = 

     dataA  dataB   key  info  dataC
0     ABC    123    a1b  infoA  aaa
1     DEF    456    b57         bbb
2     GHI    789    a22  infoC  ccc
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pandas [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) over `df1` and `df2` on columns `['key','info']`, then, use column `key` as column name to join on and use only the keys from left dataframe `how='left'`. Get the resulting column (`info_y`) into the first dataframe.

```py
df1['info'] = pd.merge(df1[['key','info']], df2[['key','info']], on='key', how='left')['info_y']
print(df1)
```

Output from *df1*

```py
  dataA  dataB  key   info dataC
0   ABC    123  a1b  infoA   aaa
1   DEF    456  b57    NaN   bbb
2   GHI    789  a22  infoC   ccc
```